# Azure bot authentication and integration in web applications

Tags: .net, azure, botframework, azure-bot-service

I am trying to build a azure bot ( using .net core) which can be integrated with multiple web applications.

I am going with root bot for authentication and skill bot approach.

Below is the part where I am struggling:

As soon as user login to a webapplication, and bot should be able to login automatically and have users identity.

Can some one help how can I achieve it. I am not finding any articles that can help me.